# how to make button in table to route to url

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, html-table

I have table `<thead>` initialized in in blade and `foreach` loop for `<tbody>` in controller

so this is how it looks in controller:

```
foreach($data as $row)
       {
        $output .= '
        <tr>

         <td>'.$row->year.'</td>

         <td>
            <a href={{url(/edit/'.$row->id.')}} class="...">Edit</a>
            <a href="#" class="...">Delete</a>
         </td>

        </tr>
        ';
       }
```

and in the blade, initialized like this:

```
<table>
       <thead>

        <tr>
         <th>Year</th>
         <th> BUTTON </th>
        </tr>

       </thead>

       <tbody></tbody>

      </table>
```

and the `script` to fetch data into the `<tbody>`:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

 fetch_customer_data();

 function fetch_customer_data(query = '')
 {
  $.ajax({
   url:"{{ route('live_search.action') }}", // live_search: is the blade where the table is
   method:'GET',
   data:{query:query},
   dataType:'json',
   success:function(data)
   {
    $('tbody').html(data.table_data); // TABLE DATA
    $('#total_records').text(data.total_data);
   }
  })
 }

 $(document).on('keyup', '#search', function(){
  var query = $(this).val();
  fetch_customer_data(query);
 });
});
</script>
```

the data and the button appear in the table but the button does not work properly. there is a problem with how I'm using the button in the table, this button: `<a href= "{{url(/edit/'.$row->student_id.')}}" class="...">Edit</a>` generates this url: `http://sms.test/%7B%7Burl(/edit/2)%7D%7D` while the url should look like this: `http://sms.test/edit/ID22` but when i change the `href= "{{url(/edit/'.$row->student_id.')}}"` to `href= "#"` it displays the `#` in the url bar. so i guess the problem is in this line `"{{url(/edit/'.$row->student_id.')}}"`

this is the route to `edit`:
`Route::get('/edit/{id}', 'StudentController@edit');`

and the `function edit` @controller looks like this:

```
public function edit($id)
    {
      $student = Student::find($id); 
      $students = Student::all();
      return view('student',['students'=>$students,'student'=>$student,'layout'=>'edit']);

    }
```

I tried every method I know but could not get it to work:( please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have Blade stuff in a string and expect it to get parsed by the compiler. Either refrain from using Blade in your template string and concatenate it like you did with the year above:

```
foreach($data as $row) {
    $output .= '
    <tr>
        <td>'.$row->year.'</td>
        <td>
            <a href="'.url('/edit/'.$row->id).'" class="...">Edit</a>
            <a href="#">Delete</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    ';
}
```

Alternatively use a custom blade template for this like you did in your `student.blade.php`. This would be a much cleaner approach.

Comment: it worked perfectly. thanks for the advice too I will try to make that<3.

Answer (score 0):

Your code in the controller just build it as a string and actually not calling the function **url()** with those params.

try to change it little bit to concat to full **href="'.url(/edit/$row->id).'"** that return and not **href={{url(/edit/'.$row->id.')}}** as it can work from the blade template itself.

like that:

```
foreach($data as $row)
   {
    $output .= '
    <tr>

     <td>'.$row->year.'</td>

     <td>
        <a href="'.url(/edit/$row->id).'" class="...">Edit</a>
        <a href="#" class="...">Delete</a>
     </td>

    </tr>
    ';
   }
```

Comment: Sure :) you are welcome to vote up and accept my answer :)